# What is the best way to to keep a Deedle Frame object growing without impacting performances?

Tags: c#, performance, deedle

I have been using C# Deedle Frame and Series objects for managing financial data, it works great and it really changes the way time series are handled in C#.

But due to the immutable implementation, each time you modify the collection, a copy is made. I am appending daily points to a series and I wondered what would be the best way to keep adding rows to my `Frame<TRowKey, TColumnKey>` without impacting the performances. (I am currently using the Append method)

I expect the number of copy operations to grow like `nbAddedRows! * nbColumns`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to create a new frame with the data you want to append. Then, instead of using the `Append` method try using one of the various `Join` methods available.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't do the trick as in this case as well as by using the Join method, a copy of the entire set is made (code decompiled with ReSharper).

Comment: Returning to the good old fashion Dictionary<DateTime, double> does the trick in this particular case.